# Telling if a method was declared using "a string"

Tags: groovy

For DSL purposes I want to detect methods defined like:

```
  def "methodName"() {}
```

or

```
  def "This is another method name"() {}
```

Is there any way to do that using reflection?

Comment: instead of reflection, AST Transformations may be the subject you need to look out for: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do what you asked, simply because there is no difference between `def foo(){}` and `def "foo"(){}` in a Groovy object.  You could use reflection to detect methods with spaces, but that doesn't (and can't) help if they don't have a space.  Maybe you should explain what you are actually trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm trying to detect some kind of methods in particular, like the "test" prefix on JUnit 3 or the @Test annotation in JUnit 4. I could resolve it using annotations, but I was wondering if I could detect the "string" methods. I've look into Spock and it uses AST transforms (it also transforms the code to allow the when:then: labels), but since I've never used AST transforms before, I was wondering if there is a reflection way of distinguish that kind of methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is not available at runtime. Even with an AST transformation, you would not be able to figure out that the method was defined using a string.

For this, you would have to write your own `AntlrParserPlugin` and use it using a custom `CompilerConfiguration`. Then in methodDef from `AntlrParserPlugin`, when the name of the method is parsed, you could check that the character before the name is a double quote. If a double quote is found, then add a custom annotation to the generated `MethodNode`, so that the information is available at runtime...